# XPATH in PHP to display text

Tags: php, xpath

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("https://digitalpool.com/tournaments/20220304-friday-night-8-ball-tournament/players");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($file);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query('*[@id="app-container"]/section/section/main/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/h4/text()[2]');

if (!is_null($elements)) {
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    echo "<br/>[". $element->nodeName. "]";

    $nodes = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

I'm using the above in an attempt to retrieve the number of players.  Instead it's throwing a multitude of errors.  I've double checked the xpath and it is indeed correct.
//*[@id='app-container']/section/section/main/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/h4/text()[2]

Looking for some guidance to simply get to the number.

Comment: `loadHTMLFile` loads a file whereas `loadHTML` loads a string of HTML - besides which the cited URL returns a 404

Comment: Corrected the URL

Comment: looks like the page content is delivered by Javascript - there are 2 ajax requests made to `https://api2.digitalpool.com/v1/graphql` - PHP DOMDocument & DOMXPath will be of no use scraping this content, consider using Node.js instead or a headless browser.